# Why liquibase does always use its own sequence?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, liquibase

I am using liquibase as a migration tool for my current project.

The problem is that I am trying to use custom sequence for auto generation ids for entities but something wrong happens.

I've defined an entity table and custom sequence as a similar below:

```
<databaseChangeLog>
<changeSet id="create_orders_table" author="I am">
    <createTable tableName="ORDERS">
        <column name="id"  type="SERIAL" valueComputed="SEQ_ORDERS.NEXTVAL" valueSequenceCurrent="SEQ_ORDERS.CURRENT"  valueSequenceNext="SEQ_ORDERS.NEXTVAL" defaultValueSequenceNext="SEQ_ORDERS.NEXTVAL">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" unique="true"/>
        </column>
        <column name="number" type="VARCHAR(64)"/>
        ...
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
<changeSet id="add_sequence" author="I am">
    <createSequence sequenceName="SEQ_ORDERS" cycle="false" minValue="1" maxValue="9223372036854775807" startValue="1" incrementBy="1"/>
</changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

But when this migration is applied I see the following table structure in postgresql:

```
CREATE TABLE public.orders
(
id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('orders_id_seq'::regclass),
"number" character varying(64),
 ...
CONSTRAINT pk_orders PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
OIDS=FALSE
);
```

First unpredictable thing for me here is why liquibase wrote its own `orders_id_seq` instead of my `SEQ_ORDERS`?

Next I wrote a typical JPA code and it's test using Spring:

```
@Entity(name = "ORDERS")
public class Order {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ORDERS_ID_GEN")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "ORDERS_ID_GEN", sequenceName = "SEQ_ORDERS")
  private long id;

  private String number; 
  //... getters,setters and other stuff
}

public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order,Long> {}
```

Test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@Rollback(value = false)
public class OrderRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager testEntityManager;

    @Autowired
    private OrderRepository orderRepository;


    @Test
    public void testThatIdsOfOrdersGenerateCorrectly(){


        Order orderOne = new Order();
        orderOne.setNumber("order-n-01");

        Order orderTwo = new Order();
        orderTwo.setNumber("order-n-02");

        Order orderThree = new Order();
        orderThree.setNumber("order-n-03");

        testEntityManager.persist(orderOne);
        testEntityManager.persist(orderTwo);
        testEntityManager.persist(orderThree);

        Assert.assertThat(orderRepository.findOne(new Long(1)),is(orderOne));
        Assert.assertThat(orderRepository.findOne(new Long(2)),is(orderTwo));
        Assert.assertThat(orderRepository.findOne(new Long(3)),is(orderThree));

    }

}
```

In test logs I see:

```
Hibernate: select nextval ('seq_orders')
...
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: is <Order(id=50, number=order-n-01, ...>
   but: was null
```

After Test is finished In DB I saw three orders with id=50,51,52

First time I thought that `orders_id_seq` increments value on 50 each time.
I was very surpised when I saw unmodified `orders_id_seq` after test (current value=1) but my SEQ_ORDERS was incremented on 1.

When I run the test once again I got next three orders with ids 100,101,102

Could someone explain me what the hell is going on here?
And how to make liquibase&postgresql do right things?

I am using: PostgreSQL 9.6(org.postgresql.9.4.1212 JDBC Driver), Liquibase 3.5.3, Spring Boot 1.5.2

Spring Boot Test Config:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.jpa.database=postgresql

spring.datasource.initialize=false
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=********
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ORDERS_TEST
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

liquibase.change-log=classpath:/db/changelog/changelog-master.xml
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you specify `serial` as the data type you should not specify any default value, because Postgres [will already do that for you](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL). The sequence and `orders_id_seq` and the default value is created by **Postgres** automatically when you use `serial` it is **not** created by Liquibase.

So if you want to use your own sequence (for whatever reason), specify the column as `integer` and specify a `defaultValueComputed` using `nextval()`. You also need to create the sequence before you create the table.

Also the syntax for getting the next value is not `sequence.nextval` but `nextval('sequence')` in Postgres:

```
<databaseChangeLog>
<changeSet id="add_sequence" author="I am">
    <createSequence sequenceName="SEQ_ORDERS" cycle="false" minValue="1" maxValue="9223372036854775807" startValue="1" incrementBy="1"/>
</changeSet>

<changeSet id="create_orders_table" author="I am">
    <createTable tableName="ORDERS">
        <column name="id"  type="integer" defaultValueComputed="nextval('seq_orders')>
            <constraints primaryKey="true" unique="true"/>
        </column>
        <column name="number" type="VARCHAR(64)"/>
        ...
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Comment: Yeah, such changeLog makes postgreSQL use my sequence but I got 50,51,52 ids anyway.

Comment: @rvit34: probably something wrong with the mapping in your obfuscation layer - I don't use Hibernate so I can't help you with that). You might want to ask a separate question for that (a question on SO should only contain  a single question). But it sounds like some kind of caching in Hibernate. Or did you maybe create the sequence with `cache="50"`?

Comment: As I see In PgAdmin, cache of my SEQ_ORDERS is 1

Comment: Thanks. I found that Hibernate by default allocates sequence values in chunks of 50, as an optimisation for insert performance. To prevent that need to specify `allocationSize = 1` on @SequenceGenerator